# Only allow HTML field to start with certain words

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a quick javascript library or code that would only allow a user to start a form input with a preset selection of words?

For example it would allow a user to start a the word "Are" or "What" but not "Why".

Comment: If `Are` and `What` are the only words allowed, why would you need to disallow `Why`, there's something wrong with your logic here ?

Comment: @adeneo I suspect "why" was merely a general example of a non-are/what word. Not something that needs to be explicitly restricted.

Comment: @user1144397 May I ask *why* you need this behavior?

Comment: Big goal is to only allow question phrases within a text field. I figure the easiest way is to force users to begin with an interrogative word.

Comment: Imho that is really bad from the user's POV. It also is not going to have have effect you are hoping for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `change` or `input` event listener to it and validate the content. To avoid false negatives with initial few letters you can start checking after the input string contains a space. You don't need a library to do that. Plain old JS will do the job.

```
var input = document.getElementById("myinput");
input.addEventListener('input', validate);

function validate(e) {
    var validStart = ['why', 'when'];
    var tmpVal;
    if (this.value.indexOf(' ') !== -1) {
        tmpVal = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();
        if (validStart.indexOf(tmpVal) === -1) {
            input.classList.add('notvalid');
        } else {
            input.classList.remove('notvalid');
        }
    } else {
        input.classList.remove('notvalid');
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ofx2yhzm/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Regex. (This is really primitive and should be improved according to your case.)

```
^(Why|Are).*$
```

HTML5 input pattern example:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^(Why|Are).*$">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dk5s0mne/).

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return validate()">
<input type="text" name="val" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
window.validate = function(){

data = document.forms['myform']['val'].value;
var starts = ['hi','he'];

for (var i = 0; i <= starts.length; i++)
    if (data.indexOf(starts[i]) === 0) return true;

return false;
}
```

And of course you could also use Regex tho I guess that's a *little* more inefficient.

Something like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/4jasrbob/

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to Strah's answer, but here it is anyway:

```
function checkValue(el) {

  // Trim only leading whitespace so responds when first space entered
  // and break into words
  var words = el.value.replace(/^\s+/,'').split(/\s+/);
  // List of allowed words
  var allowed = ['are','what'];

  // Element to write message based on source element
  var msg = document.getElementById(el.id + 'Msg');
  // Clear error message by default
  msg.innerHTML = '';

  // Only do something if at least one word has been entered
  // Could also check if first word has more letters than
  // longest allowed word
  if (words.length > 1) {

    // Check if first word is allowed
    if ( allowed.indexOf(words[0].toLowerCase()) == -1) {
      msg.innerHTML = 'Input must start with one of ' + allowed.join(', ');
    }
  }
}
```

Some markup:

```
<input id="foo" oninput="checkValue(this);">
<span id="fooMsg"></span>
```

This allows the user to at least enter a word before being given an error. They should also be given some onscreen hints to let them know which words to use, rather than having to get it wrong first (which is bound to happen a lot).